# Como alterar o atributo de um elemento em javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function changedisplay()
{
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    if (x.style.display == 'none')
    {
        x.style.display  = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.display  = 'none';
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>        
    
        <style>
            li
            {
                display: none;

            }
            

        </style>
    </HEAD>

    <body>

        <button onclick="changedisplay()">mudar</button>
        <ul>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
        </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Estou tentando fazer um menu para mobile com uma `<ul>` por padrão está display: none, quero alterar o msm block quando o usuário clicar no Menu para dar o efeito e voltar para none quando o mesmo for pressionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/getElementsByTagName) retorna uma lista de vários elementos (para ser mais preciso, retorna um [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)), então você precisa percorrer esta lista, e para cada elemento, mudar o `style` do mesmo:

```
for (let x of document.getElementsByTagName('li')) {
  if (!x.style.display || x.style.display == 'none')
    x.style.display  = 'block';
  else
    x.style.display  = 'none';
}
```

Ou:

```
let elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  let x = elementos[i];
  if (!x.style.display || x.style.display == 'none')
    x.style.display  = 'block';
  else
    x.style.display  = 'none';
}
```

Também incluí uma condição a mais (`!x.style.display`), pois na primeira vez o `display` dos elementos pode não estar definido.

Exemplo completo:

```js
function changedisplay()
{
    for (let x of document.getElementsByTagName('li')) {
      if (!x.style.display || x.style.display == 'none')
        x.style.display  = 'block';
      else
        x.style.display  = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>        
    
        <style>
            li
            {
                display: none;

            }
            

        </style>
    </HEAD>

    <body>

        <button onclick="changedisplay()">mudar</button>
        <ul>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
            <li name='li'>ASDASD</li>
        </ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```